# How to whitelist source IPs on Azure VMs fronted by Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, networking, whitelist, azure-load-balancer, azure-nsg

I have a public facing, standard sku, Azure Load Balancer that forwards the incoming requests for a certain port to a virtual machine, using load balancing rules. This virtual machine has a NSG defined at the subnet level, that allows incoming traffic for that port, with source set to as 'Internet'.

Presently, this setup works, but I need to implement whitelisting - to allow only a certain set of IP addresses to be able to connect to this virtual machine, through the load balancer. However, if I remove the 'Internet' source type in my NSG rule, the VM is no longer accessible through the Load Balancer.

Has anyone else faced a similar use case and what is the best way to setup IP whitelisting on VMs that are accessible through Load Balancer. Thanks!

---

Edit: to provide more details

[Screenshot of NSGs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtJQL.png)

These are the top level NSGs defined at the subnet.

We have a public load balancer that fronts the virtual machine where above NSGs are applied. This virtual machine doesn’t have a specific public IP and relies on the Load Balancer’s public IP.

The public Load Balancer forwards all traffic on port 8443 and port 8543 to this virtual machine, without session persistence and with Outbound and inbound using the same IP.

Below are the observations I have made so far:

- Unless I specify the source for NSG rule Port_8443 (in above table) as ‘Internet’, this virtual machine is not accessible on this port, via the load balancer’s public IP.
- When I retain the NSG rule Port_8543, which whitelists only specific IP addresses, this virtual machine is not accessible on this port, via the load balancer’s public IP – even when one of those whitelisted clients try to connect to this port.
- I tried adding the NSG rule Custom_AllowAzureLoadBalancerInBound, to a higher priority than the port_8543, but it still didn’t open up this access.
- I also tried to add the Azure Load balancer VIP (168.63.129.16) to the Port_8543 NSG, but that too didn’t open-up the access to port 8543, on load balancer’s public IP.

I have played with Load Balancing rules options too, but nothing seems to achieve what I am looking for – which is:

- Goal 1: to open-up the virtual machine’s access on port 8443 and port 8543 to only the whitelisted client IPs, AND
- Goal 2: allow whitelisted client IPs to be able to connect to these ports on this virtual machine, using the load balancer’s public IP

I am only able to achieve one of the above goals, but not both of them.

I have also tried the same whitelisting with a dedicated public IP assigned to the virtual machine; and that too loses connectivity to ports, where I don't assign 'Internet' source tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has default rules in each network security group. It allows inbound traffic from the Azure Load Balancer resources.

[image]

If you want to restrict the clients to access your clients, you just need to add a new inbound port rule with the public IP address of your clients as the `Source` and specify the `Destination port ranges` and `Protocol` in your specific inbound rules. You could check the client's public IPv4 [here](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) via open that URL on your client's machine.

Comment: Thanks Nancy. I did create an inbound rule to allow access only to these specific client machines. I did have the default Azure Load Balancer rule still effective, but I still lose ability to receive incoming traffic from my Azure Load Balancer. I even tried adding a 'Allow' rule for Azure Load Balancer VIP: 168.63.129.16 - but that too didn't allow me to receive traffic from my Load Balancer. I am basically looking for a solution that allows me to retain these NSG rules as well as access to the load balancer. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Could you tell me how can I follow your process? "I still lose ability to receive incoming traffic from my Azure Load Balancer." Do you test the NSG rules from one Azure VM to another VM and both VMs are behind Azure LB? Is the VM itself attatched a public IP? Is there any outbound rules in your LB? Could you show more details or screenshots about that?

Comment: I have provided the requested details in the question. Specifically, the NSGs work as expected for the direct access to VMs, over the VM's private IP. VM doesn't have its own public IP and there are no outbound rules in LB. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: We finally got a resolution to this issue working with the Azure support team. It turned out to be that the machine where we were testing had different IPs, and we missed adding all those to our WL rules. Once we added all those, the WL rules started to work as expected. Thanks for your response earlier. It helped in identifying the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling here:

If you are looking to whitelist an Azure VM (available publicly or privately) for few specific client IPs, below are the steps you must perform:

- Create a NSG for the VM (or subnet) - if one not already available
- Add NSG rules to Allow inbound traffic from specific client IPs on specific ports
- Add a NSG rule to Deny inbound traffic from all other sources [This is really optional but will help in ensuring security of your setup]

Also, please note that look at all public IPs that your client machines are planning to connect with. Especially while testing, use public IPs and not the VPN gateway address ranges - which is what we used and ended up getting a false negative of our whitelisting test.